# Return boolean value from MYSQL in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im working on a function which will return a boolean-value. This value represents if an user exists in the database. Currently I have this:

```
function checkIfExists(){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.body.username);
    var rows = 0;
    database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields){
      console.log(result.length);
      rows += result.length;
    });
    return rows > 0;
  }

  console.log(checkIfExists());
```

I use 'console.log(result.length)' to validate if there are results. When I test some input, I got this:

```
false
1
```

This is strange because there is one result, so rows should be equal to 1. But then it returns false instead of true. Is it possible that the value of rows isn't changed in 'database.query(...' ?

Comment: .query accepts a function as its second argument, which is called when the query is completed. In other words, the original function potentially returns before the function passed as argument into query is even called.

Comment: Have you console rows before return ? Does that contains one ?

Comment: If i put 'console.log(rows)' just before 'return rows > 0', it gives me '1'. But the function returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function `checkIfExists` is asynchronous, I think you sould use callback system like this :

```
function checkIfExists(callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.body.username);
    var rows = 0;
    database.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else {
            console.log(result.length);
            rows += result.length;
            callback(null, rows > 0);
        }
    });
}

checkIfExists(function(err, isExists) {
    if (err) {
        // An error occured
    }
    else {
        console.log(isExists);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

You also can simlify your `checkIfExists` function like this :

```
function checkIfExists(callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.body.username);
    database.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        callback(err, result ? result.length > 0 : false);
    });
}
```

More information here :
[Understanding Async Programming in Node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This code also shows the 1 and false. But then the other way around.

Comment: Thank you very much. However the function should be just called by 'checkIfExists()', so I can use it in an if-statement: 'if(checkIfExists()){.....}'

Comment: unfortunately, it's not possible to do that with asynchronous functions :/